# EC2 command not showing

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have been using AWS for quite some time. In Ec2 instance connect console, if I give a cli command as 'aws backup list-backup-jobs' , the result will be long. So we have to click enter or down arrow to see the entire result. At the end of the result, '[END]' will show. I press ctrl+C for a new command. But after that, if I type a command, it is not visible but runs. Could anyone help me resolve this?

Please suggest an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a bug (could not reproduce on my end)

If you are seeing (END) I assume you are using "less" - `aws backup list-backup-jobs | less` ? If so quit that with 'q' instead of Ctrl + C.

That might be throwing the console off on the first run.

Comment: Hi DimitriosK,

I didn't use the |less option. But pressing 'q' works perfectly. Thank you so much.